# Disable shorthand on first citation

Tags: biblatex, footnotes, biber, authoryear

Using the `authoryear` style and mainly the `\footcite` command with `biblatex` / `biber` in a document, I need the first citation of an entry to show the long title of an entry, not its shorthand, and the shorthand from the second citation onwards.
The MWE produces the entry’s shorthand from the first citation on.

I know that the `authoryear` style only shows author and year of a work, but how can I get the first citation to show the title or full information?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}
\begin{filecontents*}{./bibliography.bib}
@book{hfa,
    title = {History of the anatidae},
    shorthand = {HFA},
    author = {Duck, Donald},
    date = {2007},
    location = {Ducksborough},
    publisher = {Waterfowl Press}
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{./bibliography.bib}

\begin{document}
This essay discusses the \enquote{History of the anatidae} by Donald Duck.%
\footcite[][henceforth called HFA]{hfa}
Now, as mentioned in that work, \LaTeXe is frequently used to depict animals at the University of Ducksborough.%
\footcite[][12]{hfa}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: The first citation already only shows a shorthand entry.]

Comment: I think you are looking for `\footfullcite` that (I quote) "puts the entire citation in a footnote and adds a period at the end."

Comment: Unrelated, but note that you do not have to use the `filecontents` package anymore, as it has been integrated a while ago, so you can directly use the commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making the comment a full answer. Based on the manual `\footfullcite` will put "the entire citation in a footnote and adds a period at the end." (cf. page 113 of the biblatex manual)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}

\begin{filecontents*}{./bibliography.bib}
    @book{hfa,
        title = {History of the anatidae},
        shorthand = {HFA},
        author = {Duck, Donald},
        date = {2007},
        location = {Ducksborough},
        publisher = {Waterfowl Press}
    }
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{./bibliography.bib}

\begin{document}
    This essay discusses the \enquote{History of the anatidae} by Donald Duck.%
    \footfullcite[][henceforth called HFA]{hfa}
    Now, as mentioned in that work, \LaTeXe is frequently used to depict animals at the University of Ducksborough.%
    \footcite[][12]{hfa}
    \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Output (just the footnote):
[image: Footnote section of the output]

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the hint about filecontents. I just saw the warning about the deprecation of filecontents in the log. Also, it’s weird that after having used biblatex and biblatex-chicago for years, I never realized there was a footfullcite...

Answer (score 1):

If you change the relevant bibmacros you won't have to use a different command and you won't even have to write the "henecforth cited as ..." yourself, `biblatex` can do that automatically.

For consistency I think it makes sense to have a full first citation of works without `shorthand` as well.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear, autocite=footnote, citetracker]{biblatex}

\renewbibmacro*{shorthandintro}{%
  \iffieldundef{shorthandintro}
    {\iffieldundef{shorthand}
       {}
       {\setunit{\addcomma\space}%
        \printtext{%
          \bibstring{citedas}\space
          \printfield{shorthand}}}}
    {\setunit{\addcomma\space}%
     \printfield{shorthandintro}}}

\newbibmacro*{cite:full}{%
  \printtext[bibhypertarget]{%
    \usedriver
      {\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{default}}
      {\thefield{entrytype}}}%
  \usebibmacro{shorthandintro}}

\renewbibmacro*{cite}{%
  \ifciteseen
    {\iffieldundef{shorthand}
       {\ifthenelse{\ifnameundef{labelname}\OR\iffieldundef{labelyear}}
          {\usebibmacro{cite:label}%
           \setunit{\printdelim{nonameyeardelim}}}
          {\printnames{labelname}%
           \setunit{\printdelim{nameyeardelim}}}%
        \usebibmacro{cite:labeldate+extradate}}
       {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}}%
    {\usebibmacro{cite:full}}}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{hfa,
  title     = {History of the anatidae},
  shorthand = {HFA},
  author    = {Duck, Donald},
  date      = {2007},
  location  = {Ducksborough},
  publisher = {Waterfowl Press}
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
This essay discusses the \enquote{History of the anatidae} by Donald Duck.%
\autocite{hfa}
Now, as mentioned in that work, \LaTeXe is frequently used to depict
animals at the University of Ducksborough.%
\autocite[12]{hfa}
Lorem\autocite{sigfridsson} ipsum\autocite{sigfridsson}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: 1 Donald Duck (2007). History of the anatidae. Ducksborough: Waterfowl Press, henceforth cited as HFA. 2 HFA, p. 12. 3 Emma Sigfridsson and Ulf Ryde (1998). ‘Comparison of methods for deriving atomic charges from the electrostatic potential and moments’. In: Journal of Computational Chemistry 19.4, pp. 377–395. doi: 10.1002/(SICI)1096-987X(199803)19:4<377::AID-JCC1>3.0.CO;2-P. 4 Sigfridsson and Ryde 1998.]

---

If you like author-title short citations as well, you could use the prebuilt `verbose` styles.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=verbose]{biblatex}


\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{hfa,
  title     = {History of the anatidae},
  shorthand = {HFA},
  author    = {Duck, Donald},
  date      = {2007},
  location  = {Ducksborough},
  publisher = {Waterfowl Press}
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
This essay discusses the \enquote{History of the anatidae} by Donald Duck.%
\autocite{hfa}
Now, as mentioned in that work, \LaTeXe is frequently used to depict
animals at the University of Ducksborough.%
\autocite[12]{hfa}
Lorem\autocite{sigfridsson} ipsum\autocite{sigfridsson}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: 1 Donald Duck. History of the anatidae. Ducksborough: Waterfowl Press, 2007 (henceforth cited as HFA). 2 HFA, p. 12. 3 Emma Sigfridsson and Ulf Ryde. ‘Comparison of methods for deriving atomic charges from the electrostatic potential and moments’. In: Journal of Computational Chemistry 19.4 (1998), pp. 377–395. doi: 10.1002/(SICI)1096-987X(199803)19:4<377::AID-JCC1>3.0.CO;2-P. 4 Sigfridsson and Ryde, ‘Comparison of methods for deriving atomic charges from the electrostatic potential and moments’.]